# Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job does not run

Tags: sharepoint, moss, timer-jobs

I am testing a couple of workflows for their workflow history cleanup time intervals. The workflow History needs to be retained for a specific number of days. I have implemented the solutions recommended [here](http://mdablog.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!B0C40902E1212960!796.entry)

My problem is that, now I need to test my code to see if the workflow history is getting cleaned up after the exact number of days.

I came to know that the workflow history is cleanep up by a timer job called "Workflow Auto Cleanup" which runs daily.

But in my case, the workflow History cleanup does not seem to run, because, in "Central Administration > Operations > Timer Job Definitions > Edit Timer Job" , the last run time is shown as "N\A"

Is there anything I am missing here? What should I do to make this timer job run properly?

Update: Checking the SharePoint logs gives this message:
"Upgrade job definition already exists, waiting for the existing upgrade to complete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/9d903fe5-6344-4e9b-893e-2f6fa7779622/).

There is a hotfix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

hilarious, a hotfix to allow you install hotfixes?

The steps outlined here worked for me:
http://blogs.technet.com/manjesh/archive/2009/11/10/unable-to-run-sharepoint-configuration-wizard-error-unable-to-upgrade-sharepoint-products-and-technologies-because-an-upgrade-is-already-in-progress.aspx